# R tryCatch RODBC function issue

Tags: r, odbc

We have a number of MS Access databases on a server which are copies from remote locations which are updated overnight. We collate some of the data from these machines for reporting purposes on a daily basis. Sometimes the overnight update fails, meaning we don’t have access to all of the databases, so I am attempting to write an R script which will test if we can connect (using a list of the database paths), and output an updated version of the list including only those which we can connect to. This will then be used to run a further script which will only update the data related to the available databases.

This is what I have so far (I am new to R but reasonably proficient in SAS and SQL – attempting to use R both as a learning exercise and for potential cost savings);

```
{

# Create Store data locations listing

A=matrix(c(1000,1,"One","//Server/Comms1/Access.mdb"

,2000,2,"Two","//Server/Comms2/Access.mdb"

,3000,3,"Three","//Server/Comms3/Access.mdb"

)

,nrow=3,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)

# Add column names

colnames(A)<-c("Ref1","Ref2","Ref3","Location")



#Create summary for testing connections (Ref1 and Location)

B<-A[,c(1,4)]



ConnectionTest<-function(Ref1,Location)

{

out<-tryCatch({ch<-odbcDriverConnect(paste("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=",Location))

sqlQuery(ch,paste("select ",Ref1," as Ref1,COUNT(variable) as Count from table"))}

,error=matrix(c(Ref1,0),nrow=1,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)

)

return(out)

}



#Run function, using 'B' to provide arguments

C<-apply(B,1,function(x)do.call(ConnectionTest,as.list(x)))

#Convert to matrix and add column names

D<-matrix(unlist(C),ncol=2,byrow=T)

colnames(D)<-c("Ref1","Count")


}
```

When I run the script I get the following error message;

> Error in value[3L] : attempt to apply non-function

I am guessing this is because I am using TryCatch incorrectly inside the UDF?

Does anyone have any advice on what I am doing incorrectly, or even if this is the best way to do what I am attempting?

Thanks

(apologies if this is formatted incorrectly, having to post on my phone due to Stackoverflow posting being blocked)

Edit - I think I fixed the 'Error in value[3L]' issue by adding function(e) {} around the matrix function in the error part of the tryCatch.

The issue now is that the script just fails if it can't reach one of the databases, rather than doing the matrix function. Do I need to add something else to make it ignore the error?

Edit 2 - it seems tryCatch does now work - it processes the 
alternate function upon error but also shows warnings about the error, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the edit above, using 'function(e) {}' to wrap the Matrix function in the error section of the tryCatch fixed the 'Error in value[3L]' issue, so the script now works, but displays error messages if it can't access a particular channel. I am guessing the 'warning' section of the tryCatch can be used to adjust these as necessary.